# left join self with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

**Setup**

```
create table #history (
adddttm date,
number int
)
insert into #history values ('2013-01-01 08:56:00.000',1);
insert into #history values ('2013-01-01 08:56:00.000',2);
insert into #history values ('2013-02-13 08:56:00.000',2);
insert into #history values ('2013-02-13 08:56:00.000',3);
```

**Query**

```
select *
from #history new
left join #history old
  on new.number = old.number
where new.adddttm = '2013-02-13 08:56:00.000'
and   old.adddttm = '2013-01-01 08:56:00.000'
```

I would expect the following query to return:

```
----------|-|----------|-
2013-02-13|2|2013-01-01|2
2013-02-13|3|null      |null
```

but I never get the second row. Why does this left join skip the missing rows?

Comment: The null record is the record that doesn't exist from last month. to me this is the same as joining two different tables together, one with the previous months data and one with the current months data.  I should be able to compare all of the previous month to the current months data including rows that didn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply because of the reference to old.adddttm in the where clause.  I wrote an article  [Fun with Outer Joins](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/93039/) with a fair amount of detail as to why.  Again very simply it's because the ON clause is just for the join between the two tables and the WHERE clause is just for restrictions on the result set.  It's easy to confuse the two though.

This query will work.

```
select *
from #history new
left join #history old
  on new.number = old.number 
  and old.adddttm = '2013-01-01 08:56:00.000'
WHERE new.adddttm = '2013-02-13 08:56:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause is excluding the row.

```
select old.*
from history new
left join history old
  on new.number = old.number and old.adddttm = '2013-01-01 08:56:00.000' 
where new.adddttm = '2013-02-13 08:56:00.000'
```

Now when it doesn't get a join row, you get nulls as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns null records for number 1 and 2.

Comment: Actually this returns 4 rows.  Not just the 2 the OP wanted.  You need to keep the new.adddttm part in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Indeed @KennethFisher, I just came to the same conclusion! Didn't get a chance to test before posting